# In Flask, ajax stops after capturing 6 screens

Tags: ajax, flask

I can display 5 video files and use ajax to retrieve the data, but when I display 6 video files, ajax is　stopped.

```
@app_.route('/feed0')
def feed0():
return Response(gen(Cam()), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
:
```

Please teach me how to use ajax capturing 6 video files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.